# openpyxl find cell or row by value

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is there a method anyone knows of where I can find a cell or row in a document if I have a value other than iterating through the whole document to search for it?  Case is, I have to very large spread sheets that I need to compare and I am doing that by using a single UUID that exists in each record in each sheet.

So, basically:

```
ws1 = rows1
ws2 = rows2  
for row1 in rows1:
    uuid = row1[0].value
    comp = row1[1].value
        for row2 in rows2:
            if row2[0] = uuid
                if row2[0] = comp
                    do-stuff()
```

This seems more nested than it needs to be.  Is there a way to find the value in rows2 easier than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no other way of searching by content than going cell by cell.