# Using openpyxl to search for a cell in one column and then to print out the row for that relevant cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

For instance, I want to be able to type into my program via user input the data and then print the row relevant to that cell. Ideally, if 1/08/2016 was inputted into the program then it will run through column 'A' and then locates the relevant date. If date is found then it will print the date and then the relevant data in that row. This is what I have currently below. Any type of suggestions will be great if a direct answer cannot be found.

EDIT: I changed x to date.

```
from openpyxl import *

wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/W-_-C/PycharmProjects/IT SAT_data doc.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('101')
date = input("Prompt: ")
for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row, ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        if ws.cell(row=row, column=0).value == date:
            print(ws.cell.value)
```

Comment: You only want to look in column A for the input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openpyxl find cell or row by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903876/openpyxl-find-cell-or-row-by-value)

Comment: Think about using pandas and dataframe. For working with big excels I use pandas for fast search and analysis and then only write what is neccessary via openpyxl (sometimes can't use pandas to directly write for few limitations).

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to look in column A for the input I would do something like this:

```
for i in range(1,ws.max_row):
    if ws.cell(row=row, column=0).value == date:
        for j in range(i, ws.max_column):
            print (ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value)
```

Assuming you want to print every column on the row matching the input

Comment: Not exactly, the date will only be in column 'A' however there will be a set of data in that row that isn't the date. So I want to print the entire row via searching for the date in the first column.

Comment: For Example:   A1 = 12/06/2016 , A2 = 13/06/2016, B1 = 5, B2 = 6, C1 = 7, C2 = 9. I want to search for 12/06/2016 and print the values in row 1.

Comment: I have an alternative method figured out where I create a two-step search function where the program writes cell's and their values to a txt file, User then search's the date in a txt file and receives date and row number, the user then searches for row number and it prints the row.

Comment: Well isn't that what my example does? First it loop thru column A(1) searching for the input date, if found it loops thru and print out that row

Comment: It came up with an error, the error is: TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int().