# What is the Python Function Command For Fetching Data from a Data Table

Tags: python, command

I am new to Python. I am currently working on an app that fetches data from a Data table based on the users input. So far I can't seem to find the right set of commands anywhere. Does anyone have any tips?

In more technical terms the idea is this - user inputs data, user submits, query, fetch and retrieve, prints result... any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some more context on the problem please?

Comment: I am currently working on an app that fetches data from a Data table based on the user's input...So far I can't seem to find the right set of commands anywhere.

Comment: Is this a SQL table, or is it implemented in a python data structure?

Comment: the answer will range depending on what is creating the datatable

Comment: It's implemented in a python data structure.

Comment: What do you mean by "Data table?" Could you provide a code example of the interface to the Data table? I suggest using [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) to get the data.

Comment: @aquil.abdullah like a csv/xlsx file. I don't have any code for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an XLSX file, the answer posted here ([openpyxl find cell or row by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903876/openpyxl-find-cell-or-row-by-value)) has a way to find a row based on a specific value in a cell.

If it is a CSV file, you may need to read it and create a dictionary if there is a column of unique keys, otherwise iterate through every row each time a search term is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that should give you some ideas. **NOTE** I use StringIO just for the example so that I didn't have to use a file and so that the example would work out of the box. You can modify the code to read from an Excel file, Pandas DataFrame, database or any other type of storage. That choice is yours.

```
import csv
import StringIO

data = """date,obs1,obs2
2017-01-01,23.2,30.2
2017-02-01,14.9,13.3
"""

buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
buffer.write(data)
buffer.seek(0)


def select_action():
    menu = """Would you like to: (select a number)
1) See all data?
2) See data for a specific date?
3) Exit
-->"""
    action = raw_input(menu)
    while action.strip() not in ['1', '2', '3']:
        print "ERROR: Invalid action"
        action = raw_input(menu)

def do_action(action):
    if action == '1':
        reader = csv.reader(buffer)
        for line in reader:
            print "\t".join(field for field in line)
    elif action == '2':
        reader = csv.DictReader(buffer)
        date = raw_input("Select date: ").strip()
        for line in reader:
            if date == line['date']:
                output = ''
                for k, v in line.items():
                    output += ("%s: %s " % (k, v))
                print output

    # You could write a case for action 3, but it isn't necessary
    # the way I've written the code.    
    print "Goodbye"

def run():
    action = select_action()
    do_action(action)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I'll check this out now and see how it turns out